# Angular 9 universal Server side rendering (SSR) ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, express, nodes, server-side-rendering

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6339691)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6143792)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6167449)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6143792)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6289411)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6143792)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/dist/server/main.js:1:6396194)
```

I am getting this SSR error with Angular 9. The Express render (res.render) is not injecting, to the front, the response and request as specified in the code below:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(
        indexHtml,
        { 
           req,
           res, 
           providers: [
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
                { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res }
            ]
        }
    );
});
```

Here is the code to access it on front side

```
constructor(
            @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: any,
            ...
           ) {...}
```

The response value is `null` when console logged.

I made some research, and suspected the the error to be caused by the `css-loader` (when trying to do a `document.style`). But I have no clue on how to fix that.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.